# Arguments of polar conjugate and inverse

Tags: complex-numbers

So I've been given a complex number $z=7(cos(0.4)+i \sin(0.4))$.

I know that that for $6z$, $r$ will be $42$ and the argument, $\phi$, will remain $0.4$.

What will the argument, $\phi$, be in the case of $\bar{z}$? I know that $r$ will remain $7$.

Similarly, I know for $\frac{1}{z}$, $r$ will be $\frac{1}{7}$ but what will $\phi$ be?

Can someone explain how to get to the results?

Comment: Hint: $z \cdot \bar z = |z|^2 \in \mathbb{R}^+\,$, so the arguments of $z$ and $\bar z$ must add up to $\cdots$

Comment: Hint $\frac {1}{z}=z^{-1}$ and use De Morive's theorem.

Comment: @dxiv Is $\phi=-\frac{2}{5}$ correct for both cases?

Comment: @YahyaFarooq Both have argument $-0.4\,$ indeed.